# i have add coordinator layout

Tags: java, android

this is the error given by android studio when my apps crashes.

> Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #11: Binary XML file line #17: Error inflating class android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
>
> Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #17: Error inflating class android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
>
> Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.example.expensemanager-YyqHD9regFat63AepxJ6Yg==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.example.expensemanager-YyqHD9regFat63AepxJ6Yg==/lib/x86, /system/lib]]

Here is my code:

```
public class HomeActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {


    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);
        Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.my_toolbar);
        toolbar.setTitle("Expense manager");
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        CoordinatorLayout coordinatorLayout = findViewById(R.id.coordinator);
        DrawerLayout drawerLayout = findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, drawerLayout, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_cloused);

        drawerLayout.addDrawerListener(toggle);
        toggle.syncState();
        NavigationView navView = findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        navView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);


    }


    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        DrawerLayout drawerLayout = findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        if (drawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.END)) {
            drawerLayout.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.END);
        } else {
            super.onBackPressed();

        }
    }

    public void displaySlectedListener(int itemId) {
        Fragment fragment = null;
        if (itemId == R.id.dash_board) {

        } else if (itemId == R.id.income) {

        } else if (itemId == R.id.expense) {

        }

        if (fragment != null) {
            FragmentTransaction FT = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            FT.replace(R.id.main_frame, fragment);
            FT.commit();
        }
        DrawerLayout drawerLayout = findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        drawerLayout.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);

    }

    public void setSupportActionBar(Toolbar toolbar) {

    }


    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
        displaySlectedListener(item.getItemId());
        return true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

add compile `'com.android.support:design:xx.x.x'` to build.gradle

Comment: it s not  working can you please see my code https://github.com/nageshwor011/android-studio

Comment: I would recommend that you add some explanatory text to your answer, or you risk having it deleted as 'low quality'.